# who can explain this code that use for drop down menu? this is javascript to give unique number for every province and city to use in my php code

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a code same as this code that I can get a unique number for every province and city from two drop down list and my php code make unique number for new user.

I want to do the opposite: getting the name of a city or province from the city or province number to show the province or city name to the user after submiting.

how can I do by these values:

My form input for use this code is below and work correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadprovince();
  $(".province").closest('body').find('.city').addClass("tempst");
  loadCity($(".province").val());
  $(".province").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('body').find('.city').addClass("tempst");
    loadCity($(this).val());
  });
});

function loadprovince() {
  selectValues = {
    "11": "*****province*****",
    "42": "ny",
    "43": "gk"
  };
  $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
    $('.province')
      .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", key)
        .text(value));
  });

}

//Load city for selecte
function loadCity(province) {
  $(".tempst").find('option').remove();

  switch (province) {
    case "42":
      var selectValues = {
        "11": "*****city*****",
        "12": "TB",
        "13": "TL",
        "14": "NH"
      };

      break;
    case "43":
      var selectValues = {
        "11": "*****city*****",
        "12": "GH",
        "13": "NB"
      };

      $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
        $(".tempst")
          .append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", key)
            .text(value));
      });
      $(".tempst").removeClass("tempst");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Your Address</label><br />
<div>
  <select name="province" class="province"></select>
  <select name="City" class="city"></select>
</div>
```

My php code get number of selected province and city from above form and make unique number in this way:    `ProvinceNumber+CityNumber+Random8DigitNumber`

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP?

Comment: My php code get number of selected province and city from above form and make unique number in this way:    ProvinceNumber+CityNumber+Random8DigitNumber

Comment: But the PHP is not related to your question.

Comment: I dont think it's necessary

Comment: I just say why I want this code

Comment: thanks for your edit.I make mistake.I saw that after your edit

Comment: The `$.each()` loop should not be inside `case '43':`. Then it doesn't work when they select `ny`. It should be after the end of the `switch()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an object that maps from `ProvinceNumber` and `CityNumber` to the name:

```
const cityNames = {
    '42': {
        province: 'ny',
        cities: {
            '12': 'TB',
            '13': 'TL',
            '14': 'NH'
        },
    '43': {
        province: 'gk',
        cities: {
            '12': 'GH',
            '13': 'NB'
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you get the response from the server, you can extract the digits and look them up in the object:

```
var provinceNum = substr(response, 0, 2);
var cityNum = substr(response, 2, 2);
var cityName = cityNames[provinceNum][cityNum];
```

You can also use this object in your `loadCity` function, instead of `switch/case`.

Comment: just i want first understand what is this in javascript .is an array or another thing and how decalre???selectValues = {
        "11": "*****city*****",
        "12": "GH",
        "13": "NB"
      };

Comment: Sorry I don't understand that question. What part don't you understand?

Comment: just i want first understand what is this in javascript .is an array or another thing and how decalre???selectValues = {
        "11": "*****city*****",
        "12": "GH",
        "13": "NB"
      };  and how can i use in codes or use its indexes and vlue

Comment: It's an object literal. If you don't understand it, you need to read a Javascript tutorial, I'm not going to try to teach it here.

Comment: thanks.i looking for its name and declaration to search about that